# util.Random symbol not found

Tags: java

I was working with web services and when i compile 
my `util.Random` was not found by the compiler why? This is my code fragment

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import java.util.Random.*;

// annotation; a j2se 5 feature
@WebService
public class Card {
    Random r = new Random();

    @WebMethod

    public int getCard(){

        int random = new r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        return random;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you don't understand how import statements work. Hint: You are not trying to import every member of `java.util.Random`.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
import java.util.Random.*;
```

to this:

```
import java.util.Random;
```